# .htaccess mod_rewrite: rewriting image path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite an image path on the following URLs:

1. domain.com/system/index
2. domain.com/system/view/12345
3. domain.com/system/search/term1:/term2:data/term3:/term4:data/term5 - (this URL will contain varying amounts of data depending on what the user searches for.)

To this image:

mydomin.com/img/img1.gif

This is what I have in my .htaccess currently:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/img/img1\.gif$ /img/img1\.gif [L]
```

This rewrites URLs 1 & 2 correctly but doesn't work for URL 3. When accessing URL 3 it redirects to the following:

domain.com/system/search/term1:/term2:data/term3:/img/img1.gif

Which isn't correct. This has been driving me crazy, any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^/]+` means 1 or more characters that are not slash
you need 1 or more any characters - so instead use a dot - `.`

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/img/img1\.gif$ /img/img1\.gif [L]
```